# Does requests module do not take the full data from google(web scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-search-console

I am trying to scrape google's weather details. The thing is I am not getting all the information from the webpage. what should I do in order to get full information? I am using the requests module and beautiful soup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=weather+in+rochester"
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
something = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'wob_t'})
temp = []
for i in range(len(something)):
    temp.append(something[i].get_text())
print(temp)
```

I expect to get the temperature for 7 days but I only get it for 3 days on top of that I can not get some of the words from the google.in this example, it says something about weather like cloudy or snowy but when I try to get it it does not let me.
when I run the programme I get :

`['24°C', '11 km/h', '27°C', '14°C', '28°C', '15°C', '28°C', '16°C', '28°C', '16°C']`

But I should get a temp for 8 days.
I have checked the tags and all temp are same wob_t

Comment: why not find a weather API and use that?

Comment: It would be much easier to use a weather API such as [openweathermap.org](https://openweathermap.org/api), or [Weather Channel API](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/weather-channel)

Comment: Try adding a user agent header to your request.

Comment: I know it would be easier to use weather API but I am just trying to do web scrapping and getting this half information from Google.